# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '5 1 ' Runtime error when i provide the input as "5 1"

Tags: python-3.x

How can i take an input  in list with the test case as integer '5 1'(spacing between both integer)

```
class Total_money:
    cp=[]
    rp=[]

    def _init_(self,cost):
        self.cost=cost

    def Cost_petrol(self):
        for i in range (0,2):
            cp=int(input("Cost of  petrol is"))


    def Petrol_needed(self):

        for i in range (0,2):
            rp=int(input("Cost of  petrol is"))

    def total_money(y):
        for i in range (y):
            self.cost=cp[i]*rp[i]+self.cost
        return (self.cost)            

print("Test case:")
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
total=Total_money() 

total.Cost_petrol()
total.Petrol_needed()
Fcost=total.total_money(y)
print("Total cost to monk is:",Fcost)
```

Getting a runtime error- ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '5 1 '

Comment: `"5 1"` isn't a number, it's two. That can't be converted into one number. What's your intent?

Comment: I want to use them(integers) as two seperate inputs not one.

Comment: You can't do that. You'll have to enter the two numbers seperately and convert them to ints

Comment: but the test cases are throwing the same value in the input.ie:The question has the same input as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

> As far as i understand your question ,you want to take a space separated input which can be taken by replacing your inputs by following.

```
x,y = input().split()
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
```

but even after this your code will not run as it has a few bugs like,trying to access a global variable inside function and a few more